# Embed my website content in my sharepoint by URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, embedded

I am moving some of our organisations intranet to "Modern" sites on MS hosted Sharepoint.

As Sharepoint doesn't allow HTML editing, I've made a few pages on my website that users can embed, to pick up dynamic information etc that Sharepoint will not have.

The content varies in height, so it's impossible to get an iframe that fits without causing scroll issues.

Also my users are not web developers, so rather than teaching all my users how to use iFrames, I wanted to use the "embed with a URL" feature.

**I do not want to use iframes.**

How do I set up my website (not the SharePoint website, mine!) to allow Sharepoint to pick up the correct information to embed automatically? Is there a protocol somewhere I need to apply on my webpage? Some meta tags? it is oEmbed? Similar?

I want my users to copy a URL from my website written in a different platform not SharePoint, by me, and paste it into a SharePoint embed web part and have it embed without the user typing iframe code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having asked elsewhere, someone suggested I look at the tags on YouTube to see if anything there gave a clue how they handle embeds.

There's an oEmbed tag, which lead me to investigate how to be an oEmbed provider.

It seems you have to add a tag to your pages, which gives a link to an oEmbed endpoint, that returns JSON info about how to embed the page.

https://timnash.co.uk/becoming-oembed-provider/

Answer (score 0):

In modern page, you can try to use the [embed web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-content-to-your-page-using-the-embed-web-part-721f3b2f-437f-45ef-ac4e-df29dba74de8) to insert iFrames.

Examples and instructions:https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-embed-content-from-other-websites-in-sharepoint-online/

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to be limited to an iframe as the content can vary in height. I also want my users (who are a mixed bag of experts in many fields except computing) to be able to copy and paste a URL, rather than learning how to format an iframe.

Comment: @Hippyjim, in modern page, we cannot change the layout without the out of the box options. You can change the page layout like this:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-sections-and-columns-on-a-sharepoint-modern-page-fc491eb4-f733-4825-8fe2-e1ed80bd0899. And use the embed web part to paste the iFrames URL.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Jerry_MSFT but that is also not what I asked. I know all this. I want to know how to make MY WEBSITE work with the embed by URL feature. I want my users to paste a URL from my website and have it embed automatically within the SharePoint embed web part without them having to write the iframe tags.

Comment: @Hippyjim, for that, it may be better for you to find a custom web part for this. For out of box solution, if you want to display from an external site in a modern page, then you need to use embed.